# The solution to upvoting onself seems unnecessarily punitive

Tags: discussion

I think I understand why Stack Overflow thinks one should not up-vote oneself, and I agree with it. Even platforms like Reddit that think this is OK, automate the process so everyone up-votes themselves.

However, your particular implementation seems unnecessarily punitive. I just realized that the system seems to allow me to do this, so I clicked to confirm that it did. Now I have down-voted myself and cannot change it, if I'm getting it correctly.

What's the point of this? Why not simply disable the up-vote button for one's own posts? Whatever the intention: curiosity, malice, carelessness, it seems like there's no purpose for this other than "testing" users and penalizing curiosity or even disagreement with a debatable policy. Feels like the wrong message, IMHO.

Respectfully submitted for your consideration.

**Edit:** It would seem a negative vote for my post came in at the same time I tried to up-vote myself, giving me a false idea of what had happened. My apologies.

Comment: I think it would be awesome if you were "punished" with a downvote from Community♦ if you tried to upvote yourself. :D I'm upvoting this as if it were a FR.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both the upvote button and the downvote button are technically disabled on your own posts. You may see the score increase or decrease for a split second, but it should go back to normal within a split second (if the score actually changed, then it's likely it's someone else's vote or you need to refresh the page). You should also get a message like this (also only for a split second it feels like):

> [image: You can't vote for your own post]

You can't undo a vote that never existed.

(It's also worth noting that if there were a penalty, I would have run into it while getting this image, since I ended up upvoting and downvoting myself at least a 100 times because the message goes away so fast. The action apparently isn't rate limited either.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. However, why isn't it just disabled? Is it easier this way?

Comment: This is the correct answer. (I deleted my own answer because I decided it didn't add anything this one doesn't cover.) OP hasn't been penalized or actually cast an up- or downvote for OP's own content.

Comment: @Pablo It *is* disabled; it doesn't do anything. Are you asking why it isn't hidden entirely?

Comment: @EdCottrell I think they mean why don't the arrows just do nothing (like a disabled, unclickable button) as opposed to briefly changing and then changing back. I assume it's because it's less resource intensive to only check when the user actually tries to vote instead of checking every post on the page when it loads.

Comment: @BSMP That, and a button that does literally nothing is even more confusing. I know I’ve tried to upvote my own posts a few times by accident (stumbling across them years after I wrote them, when I had apparently forgotten about them and didn’t realize they were mine). I would have been confused if I hadn’t gotten a message of some sort.

Comment: @EdCottrell thanks. I think the following happen: I upvoted my own comment from 0 to 1. It went up for a split second and then it went do -1 with a message that "I can't upvote my own comment". I didn't realize that what likely happened was that a new downvote came through in that timespan between posting and upvoting (15 secons or so).

Comment: @PabloBarríaUrenda you aren't downvoted for attempting to upvote. If you refresh the page and it's still at -1 then unfortunately for you, you've been downvoted by _someone else_.